# ODL configuration netconf server fails

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netconf

I am a newbie to OpenDaylight. I am going to configure an interface through the RESTAPI. Here it is my following API:

http://localhost:8181/restconf/operations/network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/node/new-netconf-device/yang-ext:mount/ietf-netconf:edit-config

This is my xml code:

```
<input xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
<target>
<running/>
</target>
<config>
<interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
<interface>
<name>host-vpp1out</name>
<description>Ethernet</description>
<type xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-    
 type">ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type>
<ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <address>
    <ip>10.80.17.54</ip>
    <prefix-length>24</prefix-length>
  </address>
</ipv4>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</interface>
</interfaces>
</config>
</input>
```

However, I receive an Error from remote netconf server

[ERR] unknown element interface /

when I see the MSG from netconf server odl remove the namespaces from xml.

I really appreciate if you can help me with this issue.